# Extend Iterator with a "mean" method

Tags: rust

I'm trying to implement a `mean` method for Iterator, like it is done with `sum`.
However, `sum` is `Iterator` method, so I decided to implement trait for any type that implements `Iterator`:

```
pub trait Mean<A = Self>: Sized {
    fn mean<I: Iterator<Item = A>>(iter: I) -> f64;
}

impl Mean for u64 {
    fn mean<I: Iterator<Item = u64>>(iter: I) -> f64 {
        //use zip to start enumeration from 1, not 0
        iter.zip((1..))
            .fold(0., |s, (e, i)| (e as f64 + s * (i - 1) as f64) / i as f64)
    }
}

impl<'a> Mean<&'a u64> for u64 {
    fn mean<I: Iterator<Item = &'a u64>>(iter: I) -> f64 {
        iter.zip((1..))
            .fold(0., |s, (&e, i)| (e as f64 + s * (i - 1) as f64) / i as f64)
    }
}

trait MeanIterator: Iterator {
    fn mean(self) -> f64;
}

impl<T: Iterator> MeanIterator for T {
    fn mean(self) -> f64 {
        Mean::mean(self)
    }
}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!([1, 2, 3, 4, 5].iter().mean(), 3.);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=fbe6fa701486f0dc02f2ce80f2d03cb0&version=stable&backtrace=1)

The error:

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
  --> src/main.rs:26:9
   |
26 |         Mean::mean(self)
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type for `Self`
```

Is there any way to fix the code, or it is impossible in Rust?

Comment: Returning 0 as the mean of an empty set is a bit... arbitrary.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> like it is done with `sum`

Let's review how `sum` works:

```rust
pub fn sum<S>(self) -> S
where
    S: Sum<Self::Item>,
```

`sum` is implemented on any iterator, so long as the result type `S` implements `Sum` for the iterated value. The *caller* gets to pick the result type. `Sum` is defined as:

```rust
pub trait Sum<A = Self> {
    pub fn sum<I>(iter: I) -> Self
    where
        I: Iterator<Item = A>;
}
```

`Sum::sum` takes an iterator of `A` and produces a value of the type it is implemented from.

We can copy-paste the structure, changing `Sum` for `Mean` and put the straightforward implementations:

```rust
trait MeanExt: Iterator {
    fn mean<M>(self) -> M
    where
        M: Mean<Self::Item>,
        Self: Sized,
    {
        M::mean(self)
    }
}

impl<I: Iterator> MeanExt for I {}

trait Mean<A = Self> {
    fn mean<I>(iter: I) -> Self
    where
        I: Iterator<Item = A>;
}

impl Mean for f64 {
    fn mean<I>(iter: I) -> Self
    where
        I: Iterator<Item = f64>,
    {
        let mut sum = 0.0;
        let mut count: usize = 0;

        for v in iter {
            sum += v;
            count += 1;
        }

        if count > 0 {
            sum / (count as f64)
        } else {
            0.0
        }
    }
}

impl<'a> Mean<&'a f64> for f64 {
    fn mean<I>(iter: I) -> Self
    where
        I: Iterator<Item = &'a f64>,
    {
        iter.copied().mean()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mean: f64 = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0].iter().mean();
    println!("{:?}", mean);
    let mean: f64 = std::array::IntoIter::new([-1.0, 2.0, 1.0]).mean();
    println!("{:?}", mean);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do it like this, for example:

```
pub trait Mean {
    fn mean(self) -> f64;
}

impl<F, T> Mean for T
    where T: Iterator<Item = F>,
          F: std::borrow::Borrow<f64>
{
    fn mean(self) -> f64 {
        self.zip((1..))
            .fold(0.,
                  |s, (e, i)| (*e.borrow() + s * (i - 1) as f64) / i as f64)
    }
}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!([1f64, 2f64, 3f64, 4f64, 5f64].iter().mean(), 3.);
    assert_eq!(vec![1f64, 2f64, 3f64, 4f64, 5f64].iter().mean(), 3.);
    assert_eq!(vec![1f64, 2f64, 3f64, 4f64, 5f64].into_iter().mean(), 3.);
}
```

I used `Borrow` trait to support iterators over `f64` and `&f64`.